# Extraer dato sin insertar vínculo dinámico

Tags: excel, vba

Pregunto aquí a ver si algún experto en vb puede echarme un cable. En mi empresa tenemos un software que monitoriza la instalación. Tiene infinidad de datos que se actualizan cada pocos segundos y se almacenan datos en la base de datos. Por motivos de seguridad no nos dan acceso a esa base de datos pero si que han creado una pequeña aplicación (app.exe) que hace de conector/puente y permite insertar links dinámicos en excel con cada uno de los datos de la aplicación.
En VBA lo que hago es añadir esos datos/variables de la aplicación a una hoja y, manteniendo app.exe abierta, los datos se van actualizando al mismo ritmo del software. Yo, en vba hago esto: `sht.Cells(2, 4).FormulaArray = "=DDEAPP|VAR_V!TRION_ST"` y así inserto en esa celda el vínculo dinámico. (Recordemos que para que se muestre un valor la aplicación app.exe debe estar corriendo en el equipo. En caso contario se muestra #ERROR)

Y aquí viene mi duda: ¿sería posible capturar esos valores sin tener que insertarlos en una celda? Hay algún modo de hacer eso en VBA?
He preguntado al departamento de IT pero piensan que quiero acceso directo a la bbdd y por motivos de seguridad no dan esos accesos. No sé si existirá algún modo o método con el que intentar conectar a esa app.exe e ir solicitando el dato en concreto que necesite y almacenarlo por ejemplo en un array.

¿Creeis que es posible? ¿Se os ocurre alguna idea?

Gracias.

Editado para añadir algo más de info:
Todas las fórmulas/variables tienen cosas en común, por ejemplo todas están formadas por DDEAPP|VAR_V!. Os pongo seis de estas variables para que tengáis algo más claro esto:

```
AT1 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A1
AT2 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A2
AT3 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A3
AT4 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A4
AT5 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A5
AT6 =DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A6
```

Comentar que esas variables las obtengo de una aplicación de la empresa. Dicha aplicación muestra paneles con gráficos y datos de cada zona y tiene una opción para "extraer" ese dato en forma de vínculo dinámico. Voy al dato deseado y con un botón que dice "Enlace dinámico" se queda copiado el link en memoria. Luego en Excel utilizo Pegado Especial > Pegar vínculos y aparece esa variable en una celda.

No puedo subir captura porque tengo esas url capadas pero para que os hagais una idea. Con la variable AT1 como ejemplo:

Así inserto la fórmula con vba en la celda:

```
sht.Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = "=DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A1"
```

El valor devuelto, de todas las variables es un número.

En la barra de fórmulas, aparece así: `{=DDEAPP|VAR_V!PIC_A1}`

He estado mirando también lo que propone otro usuario, DDEInitiate y DDERequest, pero no tengo claro qué parámetros utilizar, pues no tengo nada de documentación de esa app.

Comment: Hola, coloca algún ejemplo o ejemplo de cómo quedan esos datos en las celdas de Excel para darnos ideas y poder ayudarte.

Comment: No lo veo posible. Tu función `DDEAPP|VAR_V!TRION_ST` no está integrada en Excel de manera natural, así que no puedes acceder a ella desde el objeto `WorksheetFunction` que sería lo que necesitarías para llevarte el resultado a una variable (y aun así tengo mis dudas). Además, si te cargas el vínculo ya no se actualizaría entiendo y pones que actualizáis cada pocos segundos. No se me ocurre ninguna manera de poder hacerlo, la verdad.

Comment: Gracias @Esei . Eso me temo, que no hay modo posible utilizando esa función. 

Abraham Valencia, los datos en las celdas son números. La fórmula matricial que indico en el post "engancha" con la aplicación y devuelve el valor de esa variable.
Gracias a ambos.

Comment: Hola nuevamente. Era evidente que dicha función proviene de una librería generada probablemente por el equipo de TI de tu oficina y que está vinculada al exe que mencionas. Te preguntaba por lo que ves en las celdas ya que me llamó la atención el uso de FormulaArray. Dado que mencionas que ves números ¿Se dejan copiar como valores para trasladarlos a otra celda? De ser sí la respuesta, creo que ya sé cómo solucionar tu dilema. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @AbrahamValencia. Las fórmulas, para que muestren valores, debo escribirlas como si de fórmulas matriciales se tratara, de ahí el FormulaArray. Los valores de esas celdas pueden luego copiarse a otras celda o donde se quiera.
Gracias.

Comment: Abre la ventana inmediato y prueba esto:

MsgBox evaluate("=DDEAPP|VAR_V!TRION_ST")

Comenta qué ocurre.

Comment: Hola, al hacer eso me muestra el valor de esa variable. El único inconveniente es que para que muestre el valor tiene que haber ya una celda con esa fórmula. Si esa fórmula no existe en una hoja me tira un error 2042.

Comment: Bueno, he estado investigando un poco, y creo que puedes solucionarlo con el método 'Application.DDERequest'. Te paso enlace a la documentación oficial, que contiene un ejemplo de código que te puede servir: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.dderequest

Comment: Estimado @dogwall es que sigue habiendo detalles que no has comentado. El archivo en que usas la macro ¿Es cualquiera o es uno que te dieron? ¿Cómo se llama la hoja en donde insertas la fórmula con la macro? ¿Hay rangos con nombre? ¿Hay Tablas de Excel? Por favor edita tu pregunta y adjunta captura de pantalla de la barra de fórmulas de al menos DOS celdas y, asimismo, captura de las celdas directamente. También envía/comenta si dicha fórmula varía y/o hay otras, para entenderla mejor y ver/saber si es una UDF de librería externa o una rutina. Saludos.

Comment: El archivo lo he creado yo. Las variables/fórmulas las obtengo yo de una aplicación de terceros (de la empresa) y las inserto yo en mi excel para añadir las que necesite cada departamento. La hoja se llama DATOS y no tiene ni rangos con nombre ni tablas. La fórmula varía, hay una fórmula para cada variable ("=DDEAPP|NOMBRE_VARIABLE"). Mañana en el trabajo hago una captura pero te adelanto que en las celdas sólo se ven los datos de obtienen esas fórmulas. Gracias.

Comment: Nol olvides: Captura de la barra de fórmulas y de las celdas (aparte) y, he ahí otro detalle ¡Son varias de las que tú llamada variables! Entiendo entonces que el "común" es "DDEAPP" ¿Cierto? Eso de las variables era clave, pero bueno, por lo que vas diciendo son varias ¿De dónde las sacas y/o sabes cómo usarlas? Por lo que vas diciendo, sí podrá obtenerse los resultados en variables sin insertar las cosas en celdas, al menos eso parece hasta el momento.

Comment: Hola, he editado con algo más de info, a ver si te es útil.

Comment: Hola nuevamente. Por eso la importancia de los detalles. No se trata de funcione so rutinas de librerías asociadas a la otra aplicación, sino de vínculos dinámicos externos como bien ya decía José Luis, tecnología sobre todo usada a fines de los 90 en realidad. Con eso queda descartada una forma de capturar esas variables de modo directo con VBA, necesariamente se tiene que usar DDE como ya te indican, siendo el dilema que solo los que conocen la aplicación pueden darte los parámetros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange), es una tecnología que permite el intercambio de datos entre aplicaciones bajo windows, usando "conectores". Ya está obsoleto porque presentaba graves fallas de seguridad, pero aún está disponible y puede resultar muy adecuada en entornos controlados o cerrados.

Según he podido deducir de tu pregunta, la app que conecta tu excel con la aplicación que te proporciona los datos sería el conector DDE, ya que la estructura de la "fórmula" que pones así lo indica.

Si es así, puedes usar los métodos disponibles DDE para asignar el valor obtenido a una variable, y trabajar con ella como gustes. Para hacerlo, siguiendo el código de ejemplo que puedes encontrar en la documentación oficial de microsoft, deberías usar los siguientes parámetros:

```
channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate( _ 
 app:="DDEAPP", _ 
 topic:="VAR_V") 
myvar = Application.DDERequest(channelNumber, "TRION_ST") 
Worksheets("Tu_hoja").Cells(1, 1).Value = myvar 
Application.DDETerminate channelNumber
```

Sin tener acceso a la app y a tu hoja, me resulta imposible probar si funciona, pero deberías de este modo poder acceder al valor que deseas sin problemas.

Debes, además, tener en cuenta la velocidad a la que se suministran esos datos por la app (unos 10 ms), que suele ser mucho mayor que la que puede ofrecer excel para mostrar los datos en una celda (unos 120 ms), por lo que los cálculos que hagas pueden mostrar inconsistencias.

Espero haberte puesto en el camino de la solución.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las respuestas y consejos. Creo que esta es la única forma adecuada de aproximar una solución a mi problema. Probaré este método.
Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Comento de nuevo para confirmar que la solución funciona perfectamente. 
Gracias a todos.